# Using custom uiview in viewcontroller

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xib

I'm trying to use a custom uiview that is in a xib file. I'm a beginner and don't know where to start. I have this so far, but I  don't know what I should set my placeholder view equal to

edit: full viewController:

```
import UIKit

class Viewcontroller: UIViewController {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var placeholderView: UIView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        placeholderView = view
        
    }
    
    class func instanceFromNib() -> CustomView {
            let view = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! CustomView
            return view
    }
```

Comment: "to use a custom uiview that is in a xib file" doesn't tell the whole story.  Where and how is that `UIView` object going to be used?

Comment: I currently have a uiview inside a uiviewcontroller that’s a placeholder. I’m trying to replace the placeholder uiview with different customViews. I’m trying to start with this first customView but it doesn’t change when I set placeholderView = view

Comment: And where do those four lines of code come from?  Unless you specify the class name, others won't be able tell where you are writing code.

Comment: I posted the whole viewController now

Comment: placeholderView = view doesnt do anything

Comment: Do you have a subclass file (not .xib but .swift) of `UIView`?

Comment: Yes I have the file

Comment: You can not replace one view with another view. Add CustomView as subview.
Remove this line 
 placeholderView = view
And instead of this add below code.
let customView = self. instanceFromNib()
customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
customView.frame = placeholderView.bounds
placeholderView.addSubview(customView)

Comment: For let customView = self.instanceFromNib() I get an error that says “Static member ‘instanceFromNib’ cannot be used in instance of type ‘Viewcontroller’ “

Answer (score 1):

A. Let me suppose that you have a xib file titled 'TestView.'  Also let me suppose that you have a subclass file of `UIView` titled 'TestView.'
B. Select your xib file.  And select File's Owner.  And set the class to TestView (the name of the subclass file).
C. Open the xib file with Interface Builder.  Select 'Custom View.' (in the middle pane)  IBOutlet-Connect this view to your `UIView` swift file.  For example, name it like the following.  @IBOutlet var customView: NSView!
D. This subclass file should have the following.

```
import UIKit

class TestView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TestView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```

E. Open the storyboard.  Drag and drop a Custom View onto the view controller scene.  Under the identity inspect, set the class name to TestView.
F. IBOutlet-connect the custom view object in the view controller like the following.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var testView: TestView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

That's all.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific, but I eventually am going to need to change the placeholderView to multiple different customViews so I can’t just go into the storyboard and change the class to one customView